# Request was neither completed nor rejected within 1 second Scala Spray Testing

Tags: scala, spray

I currently testing a web service, and I keep on running into an error where the web service test is failing because it is timing out. I'm trying to extends that timeout to be 5 seconds long. I'm trying to [mimic a solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spray-user/o8DtI6VUMbA) that some one posted on the Scala Spray google groups forum to no avail. Here is the code I am trying to use in my test:

```
import akka.testkit._
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import com.github.nfldb.config.{NflDbApiActorSystemConfig, NflDbApiDbConfigTest}
import org.scalatest.MustMatchers
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import spray.testkit.Specs2RouteTest
import spray.routing.HttpService
import spray.http.StatusCodes._
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._
import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._
import concurrent.duration._

/**
 * Created by chris on 8/25/15.
 */
class NflPlayerScoringSvcTest extends Specification with Specs2RouteTest  with NflPlayerScoringService
  with NflDbApiDbConfigTest with NflDbApiActorSystemConfig {
  import PlayerScoreProtocol.playerScoreProtocol
  implicit def actorRefFactory = actorSystem
  implicit def default(system: ActorSystem = actorSystem) = RouteTestTimeout(new DurationInt(5).second.dilated)

  "NflPlayerScoringSvc" should {

    "return hello" in {
      Get("/hello") ~> nflPlayerScoringServiceRoutes ~> check {
        responseAs[String] must contain("Say hello")
      }
    }

    "calculate a player's score for a given week" in  {
      import PlayerScoreProtocol.playerScoreProtocol
      Get("/playerScore?playerId=00-0031237&gsisId=2015081551") ~> nflPlayerScoringServiceRoutes ~> check {
        val playerScore :  DfsNflScoringEngineComponent.PlayerScore = responseAs[DfsNflScoringEngineComponent.PlayerScore]
        playerScore.playerId must be ("00-0031237")
      }
    }

  }
}
```

and here is the error that I am receiving:

```
> test-only *NflPlayerScoringSvcTest*
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/chris/dev/suredbits-dfs/target/scala-2.11/test-classes...
15:54:54.639 TKD [com-suredbits-dfs-nfl-scoring-NflPlayerScoringSvcTest-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO  akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
15:54:55.158 TKD [NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] INFO  akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
15:54:55.228 TKD [NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] INFO  test test test - Trying to find score for player: 00-0031237 and optional gsisId: Some(2015081551)
15:54:55.228 TKD [NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] INFO  test test test - Searching for player 00-0031237 with optional game: Some(2015081551)
15:54:55.268 TKD [NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO  c.s.d.n.s.NflPlayerScoringSvcTest - Creating database for class com.suredbits.dfs.nfl.scoring.NflPlayerScoringSvcTest
[info] NflPlayerScoringSvcTest
[info] 
[info] NflPlayerScoringSvc should
[info] + return hello
[info] x calculate a player's score for a given week
[error]    Request was neither completed nor rejected within 1 second (NflPlayerScoringSvcTest.scala:33)
[info] 
[info] 
[info] Total for specification NflPlayerScoringSvcTest
[info] Finished in 1 second, 310 ms
[info] 2 examples, 1 failure, 0 error
[info] ScalaTest
[info] Run completed in 3 seconds, 455 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 0
[info] Suites: completed 0, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 0, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] No tests were executed.
[error] Failed: Total 2, Failed 1, Errors 0, Passed 1
[error] Failed tests:
[error]     com.suredbits.dfs.nfl.scoring.NflPlayerScoringSvcTest
[error] (test:testOnly) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
[error] Total time: 11 s, completed Aug 25, 2015 3:54:56 PM
> 15:54:56.799 TKD [NflDbApiActorSystemConfig-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] INFO  c.s.d.n.s.NflPlayerScoringSvcTest - Calculating score for game: NflGame(2015081551,Some(56772),2015-08-16T00:00:00.000Z,NflPreSeasonWeek1,Saturday,2015,Preseason,true,HomeTeam(MIN,26,9,14,3,0,2),AwayTeam(TB,16,3,6,7,0,1),2015-05-22T21:54:43.143Z,2015-08-16T17:29:01.729Z) and player: NflPlayer(00-0031237,Some(T.Bridgewater),Some(Teddy Bridgewater),Some(Teddy),Some(Bridgewater),MIN,QB,Some(2543465),Some(http://www.nfl.com/player/teddybridgewater/2543465/profile),Some(5),Some(11/10/1992),Some(Louisville),Some(2),Some(74),Some(215),Active)
```

can anyone provide any insight as what to what I can do to extend the time timeout time on Scala Spray?

Comment: Have you tried `implicit val defaultTimeout = RouteTestTimeout(5.seconds.dilated)` instead?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
  implicit def default(implicit system: ActorSystem) = RouteTestTimeout(new DurationInt(5).second.dilated(system))
```

I have to explicitly pass for `system` parameter to the `dilated` method because of implicit conflicts in Scala.

Comment: Is there a configurable solution instead?  some `akka-http.timeout = 5 s` thing we can put into application.conf?

Comment: @tdawg Would you mind correcting that to 'timefactor'.

Comment: @TonyZ Please change it to  akka.test.timefactor=5.0 . You missed a 'c' in 'timefator'.

Comment: `akka.test.timefactor=5.0`https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/main/akka-testkit/src/main/resources/reference.conf#L12

Answer (score 14):

Similar to the previous answer, but a bit shorter

```
  implicit def default(implicit system: ActorSystem) = RouteTestTimeout(5.seconds)
```

Comment: Needs `import scala.concurrent.duration._` to compile. Most Scala people might know that but if one doesn't, it's tedious to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the change which you will need to make -

```
implicit def default(implicit system: ActorSystem): RouteTestTimeout = RouteTestTimeout(new DurationInt(8).second.dilated(system))
```